# Detect other apps being launched

Tags: android, android-service

I have this code snippet that would supposedly detect other apps being launched and launch an activity before proceeding to that app. The problem is it's not effective towards other applications but only detects my own app being launched and and not the other applications. Please help me guys, it's my project and I need to implement this properly, and none of the codes out there work.

```
private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
     String activityOnTop;
     ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
     ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
     activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();

     if(activityOnTop.equals("com.appcontroller"))
     {
      pActivity = activityOnTop.toString();
     }
     else
     {
      if(activityOnTop.equals(pActivity) || activityOnTop.equals("com.appcontroller"))
      {

      }
      else
      {
       Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, BreakTimeView.class);
          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(i);
          Toast.makeText(MyService.this, pActivity, 1).show();
          pActivity = activityOnTop.toString();

      }
     }




    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect App launch in live. Your method detect only once, top running task. You need to make a service and for exemaple, every one second start your method (check top running Task). But it is a very bad practice. You will kill your battery very fast.